# Error número 1064 (42000) en MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Me da un error de sintaxis al intentar borrar una tabla y desconozco cómo solucionar este problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema ocurre porque `group` es el nombre de tu tabla pero tambien es una palabra reservada en la sintaxis de mysql, debes ponerla entre comillas:

```
DROP TABLE `group`;
```

Anexo la lista de [palabras reservadas](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html).

Comment: Muchas gracias, estaba probando las comillas pero eran las incorrectas.